# How to replace 3rd word in a line using sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, replace

This is my 3rd post in the process of learning sed. I have a hypothetical requirement. I want to be able to replace 3rd word in each line by 'was', where words are delimited by space(s).

```
bash$ cat words
hi this is me here
hi this   is me again
hi   this   is me yet again
 hi  this   is     me
```

Desired output:

```
hi this was me here
hi this   was me again
hi   this   was me yet again
 hi  this   was     me
```

Could people please help with how to do it with sed. I tried a few executing instructions, but didn't work. 
Thanks,

Jagrati

I found it! I found it!

Okay, I got the right instruction at last. This works:

```
sed -e 's/[^ ]*[^ ]/was/3' words
```

Answer (score 7):

if you do not care about formatting, this is a simpler approach

```
$ awk '{$3="was"}1' file
hi this was me here
hi this was me again
hi this was me yet again
hi this was me
```

Comment: +1, awk is nice, have just begun reading the awk programming language.

Comment: What means the 1 between `}` and `'`?

Answer (score 5):

I always do it like this: match the first and second word using *groups*, and then replace them with themselves using a *backreference*.

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) is/\1 \2 was/'
```

Comment: This will fail because of the uneven number of whitespaces.

Comment: True, when I tried it, this was able to replace in the first line, but not in later ones.

Comment: sed 's/^ *\([^ ]*\)\ \+\([^ ]*\) \+is/\1 \2 was/' file > result

Comment: I know, I was demonstrating the approach and I trust that you can tweak the regex yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This looks at word boundaries rather than only whitespace so it works when there is punctuation, too. It requires GNU `sed`:

```
$ cat words
hi this is me here
hi this   is me again
hi   this   is me yet again
 hi  this   is     me
 hi   this   "is,  me
$ sed 's/\w\+\(\W\)/was\1/3' words
hi this was me here
hi this   was me again
hi   this   was me yet again
 hi  this   was     me
 hi   this   "was,  me
```

Answer (score 0):

In any type of sed:

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\(.*\)$/\1was\2/' words
```